# Oracle query expression too long to execute

Tags: sql, oracle

The query is something like

```
select type from table1 where id in (129320, 329903, ......);
```

The id list is very long, about 35k characters and it just won't load correctly.

Is there any other way to execute the query?

EDIT:
I read the other post and changed id in (123456, 123457,...) to (1,id) in ((1,123456),(1,123457),...) but still the same problem.

I copied the long query and pasted it to the SQL plus console and it only pasted a small portion of it.

Comment: Where does the list come from? Is it a result of another query?

Comment: Do you have an index on id?

Comment: The list comes from my boss. It is not a result of any query.